# What is the brown ship in the Star Wars 2012 advent calendar?

Tags: star-wars, advent-calendar

The brown boxy ship is shown in the ad, but I have no idea what it is? My son was waiting all day for me to get home and tell him, but I can't figure it out!

[image: Brown boxy ship]

Answer (score 10):

According to [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=9509-6) it is a [Trade Federation MTT](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Multi-Troop_Transport)

Comment: Same on Brickset, according to which "[we can all see it's an MTT](http://www.brickset.com/news/article/?ID=4979)". I'll be honest, I don't who "we" is, but it sure doesn't include me either.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a Trade Fedration MTT from episode III.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This answer does give a lot of information (The relatively short answer from McKay already refers to the same vehicle with more details and links).  If this is your first time on a StackExchange site I invite you to read the FAQ (link at the top right). This will show you how you can ask and answer questions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32942/discussion-on-answer-by-farid-what-is-the-brown-ship-in-the-star-wars-2012-adven).